# How do I receive the birthday of the logged in user? (Google-SignIn, oAuth)

Tags: javascript, google-signin, google-oauth

I created a page where a user is able to login with his Google account. 
The scope for the birth date is added and the signIn-popup (picture) asks for the permission.

My question is now: How do I get the birth date?
I get the name, profile pic, and email, but no birth date.

```
var startApp = function () { 
    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', onGapiLoaded);
        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
            // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read'
        });
        attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
    });
};
```

---

```
function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function (googleUser) {
            var GoogleUser = auth2.currentUser.get();
            console.log(GoogleUser);
            var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            verifyGoogleToken(id_token, function (payload) {

            });

        }, function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
        });
}
```

[Google Sign-in popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrY5X.png)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get